# Jquery Expandable Grid System

Tags: jquery, grid, wordpress

Greetings mighty stackoverflowies!
I have been searching everywhere to find a grid system that works exactly like the one located here: http://www.colincowieweddings.com/. Has anyone seen a jquery / javascript grid like this? The site will be built using Wordpress so a plugin would probably work as well. I've searched for hours and come up with some that are close, but nothing that compares. Please help!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could share what alternatives you have discarded.

Comment: I ended up using this plugin instead. http://codecanyon.net/item/grid-accordion-responsive-wordpress-plugin/7788530